# Swift Local Notification - Only need it once per day (Showing Notification to much)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, notifications, uilocalnotification

I am currently making a app and trying out Local Notifications. I have it all set up and would like it to repeat every day.

I have the Notification working (Set to 5 seconds for testing) but problem is they keep firing. It will send one after 5 seconds then another then another anything I'm doing wrong?

I have this code in my App Delegate (did finishloadingwithoptions)

```
 let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    localNotification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Day
    localNotification.timeZone = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().timeZone
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.alertBody = "notification body here!"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

would only like the local notification to fire once then repeat the next day.

Would appreciate any help. Hope it all made sense

Comment: Note that iOS 10 introduced a brand new User Notifications framework. Looking at your code it looks like you are using the old framework. You may want to consider using the new notification framework.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, have you tried to delete all notifications?

UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)

comment your code /* code */ and

```
   for notification in    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications as!    [UILocalNotification] { 
   UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(notification)
 }
```

Comment: No where would i put that? At the end of this code or the start?